# grapecity excel to pdf shrink to fit

Tags: java, excel, pdf, apache-poi

When converting excel to pdf using apache POI it is splitting the excel sheet into 2 pdf pages.
How i can fit the whole sheet into 1 pdf page using the grapecity or a free library

Comment: `Apache poi` does not provide any `Excel` to `PDF` conversion. So how are you doing that conversion? By reading `Excel` using `apache poi` and writing the `PDF` using any other library? If so then the question relates to that other library rather than to `apache poi`.

Comment: You are right i edited my question, do you know any other free library that can solve my problem.